# Python: Stop function from execution

Tags: python, python-3.x

My task is the following:

1. Press F on Keyboard
2. Execute function in another script
3. Press F again on Keyboard and stop execution of the script I just started.
4. Maybe Press F again and start all over.

To make things easy, I wrote a function **PrintNumbers.py**.
I don't want to run into a forever loop, so i stop the function after counting to 10.
In reality, I want my code to be executed forever until I tell it to stop.

```
import time

global stopnow
stopnow = False

def stopPrinting():
    global stopnow
    stopnow = True
    
def PrintNumbers():
    global stopnow
    x = 0
    while (x < 10) and not stopnow:
        x = x + 1
        #if x == 5:
        #    stopPrinting()
        print('X is: %s\Stopnow is %s' % (x, stopnow))
        time.sleep(1)

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    PrintNumbers()
```

Now i try to call it from another file, **main.py**:

```
import keyboard
import time
import PrintNumbers as pN
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
IsPressed = False
# once you press the button('f') the function happens once
# # when you release the button('f') the loop resets

while True:
    if not keyboard.is_pressed('f'):
        IsPressed = False
        pN.stopnow
    while not IsPressed:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('f'): 
            print('pN now counting to 10!')
            IsPressed = True
            pN.PrintNumbers()
```

So - i get it, I "fire and forget" my pN.Printnumbers, but I can't find a single example in the WWW how to solve this issue.

I even spend hours on TkInter to make this work with a Start and Stop Button, only to realize that my mainloop freezes during the execution.
Even Threading is not working and I'm getting frustrated.

Really looking forward to your support.

PS:
I would love to see and really appreciate Copy&Paste solutions so that I can try them myself and understand what you experts are suggesting.

Kind regards,
ChrIsso!

Comment: It would be more useful to show your attempts with Tkinter and/or threads; use of something like that is **necessary**, so there’s not going to be a useful answer to this as written.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to interact with the function as you have outlined.
Doing it with Tkinter adds a level of complication because you have to deal with the GUI thread, but it's not too bad. I'll show an example in tkinter using a **bind**:

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Tk): #Main window
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.output = False
        self.num = 0
        self.text = Text(self)
        self.text.pack()
        self.bind('<f>', self.OnKeyPress) #The bind creates a link between pressing f and "App.OnKeyPress"
        self.NumberOutput()

    def NumberOutput(self):
        if self.output:
            self.text.insert('end', str(self.num))
            self.num += 1
        self.after(1000, self.NumberOutput) #using after(ms, function) keeps the GUI from locking

    def OnKeyPress(self, event):
        self.output = not self.output
        self.num = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I will leave it as an exercise to move the number stuff to it's own script file.

Note: You can use bind to bind to **any function**, not just something defined in App.

Comment: Hi Jared,
highly appreciated, thank you very much.
Your code is very very complicated for me as a beginner, it will take me some time to understand this.
self.after is something i heard about but didn't understand yet why this is neccessary.

What is `self.output = not self.output` used for?

Comment: Hi Jared,
you code runs fine - however is not exactly what I'm looking for i guess.
So I changed  `def NumberOutput(self):
        if self.output:
            pN.PrintNumbers()`

When i press f to stop the execution, the whole pN.PrintNumbers does a complete iteration and stops afterwards. But i want pN.PrintNumbers to add numbers to infinity and tell it to stop when I command it to...

Comment: @ChrIsso If you call a function inside of tkinter, the GUI stops executing until that function is finished. What this means is, you need to either have the GUI thread call your number generator once per second using something like self.after(1000, self.CallNumberOutput), or you need to start your number generator in a separate thread. This is a limitation of the way tkinter is written since it is interfacing with C code. If you go the thread route, you need a synchronization object to send the on/off command to the number generation thread. I would suggest a queue (Module queue.Queue)

Answer (score 0):

my code is too long for a comment, so I post this as an answer.

Here is my try with Tkinter and a process.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import PrintNumbers as pN
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue   

#################
# Main Functions
#################

def clickedStart():
    #pN.PrintNumbers()
    
    myProcess1 = Process(target=pN.PrintNumbers(), args=())
    myProcess1.start()   
    print(f'Process1 is alive: {myProcess1.is_alive()}')
    myProcess1.kill()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'Process1 is still alive: {myProcess1.is_alive()}')
    
#################
# TK Inter Design
#################
window = Tk()
window.title("Start/Stop Counting")

#window.geometry('350x200')

startbtn = Button(window, text="Start",command=lambda: clickedStart())
startbtn.grid(column=1, padx=20,pady=20,row=0)
stopbtn = Button(window, text="Stop")
stopbtn.grid(column=3, padx=20,row=0)

global queue
queue = Queue()

window.mainloop()
```

However, my Tkinter Windows freezes completely until the process is finished.
I can't move the window, i can't click stop - nothing.